# How to format a specific column in the output 'for c in df' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I want to format the output for 'Income' and 'Debt' as a currency and only format those columns.

I'm aware of how to format values as a currency using:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency
```

How would / do I incorporate this into some but not all of my output of the following script:

```
for c in df.select_dtypes('float64').columns:
    print(f"{c}: \n\n{round(df[c].agg(['mean', 'std', 'var']), 2)}\n")
```

[image]

Do let me know if you need clarification as to my objective or additional comments.

Comment: If you can come up with with a `.format` string for each column you could use `zip` to mix the column info with the format string.

Comment: Could you illustrate/ show how to do that exactly? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

pandas's built-in printing is convenient, but quite limited.  If it doesn't do what you need, then you do it by hand:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(size=(10,4))*100
x[:,2] *= 10000
print(x)

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['age','tenure','income','debt'])
print(df)

formats = [
    "{:12.2f}",
    "{:12.2f}",
    "${:11,.2f}"
]

for c,f in zip(df.select_dtypes('float64').columns,formats):
    col = df[c].agg(['mean','std','max']).tolist()
    print(f"{c}:")
    for name,val in zip(("mean"," std"," max"),col):
        print( name, f.format(val) )
```

Output:

```
[[5.67731647e+01 3.27898483e+01 2.23768614e+05 3.33362570e+01]
 [1.17460072e+01 1.04095133e+01 4.78783055e+05 3.97103367e+01]
 [2.60210356e+01 9.03336907e+01 2.40523979e+05 6.47089948e+01]
 [2.47407520e+01 4.34493721e+01 4.12519345e+05 2.38719333e+01]
 [8.31695593e+01 8.27205911e+01 2.31419302e+05 3.04190508e+01]
 [4.49907909e+01 7.93757791e+00 2.71952760e+04 3.82195704e+01]
 [8.42146402e+01 9.43830267e+01 8.53691288e+05 4.09094781e+01]
 [7.25031057e+01 5.05113468e+01 6.33643534e+04 3.06793344e+01]
 [8.73777287e+01 3.60107835e+01 5.79718932e+05 2.45306776e+01]
 [2.26262390e+00 6.05532520e+01 7.44109019e+05 2.07672676e+01]]
         age     tenure         income       debt
0  56.773165  32.789848  223768.614206  33.336257
1  11.746007  10.409513  478783.054715  39.710337
2  26.021036  90.333691  240523.979314  64.708995
3  24.740752  43.449372  412519.345013  23.871933
4  83.169559  82.720591  231419.301903  30.419051
5  44.990791   7.937578   27195.275977  38.219570
6  84.214640  94.383027  853691.287782  40.909478
7  72.503106  50.511347   63364.353358  30.679334
8  87.377729  36.010784  579718.931512  24.530678
9   2.262624  60.553252  744109.019488  20.767268
age:
mean        49.38
 std        31.97
 max        87.38
tenure:
mean        50.91
 std        30.99
 max        94.38
income:
mean $ 385,509.32
 std $ 278,493.14
 max $ 853,691.29
```